# Escaping a Single Quote in str_replace for Nav Function

Tags: php, functions, escaping

I'm trying to modify a nav walker so that it displays the menu item's description. I'm basing my solution off of https://themefoundation.com/menu-item-descriptions/, and have provided the function below.

The problem is that when a menu item's title contains an apostrophe (single quote), it seems to break the str_replace() function. I'm hoping this is an easy fix and appreciate your help.

Here's my current function:

```
function prefix_nav_description( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
 if ( !empty( $item->description ) ) {
    $item_output = str_replace( '">' . $args->link_before . $item->title, '">' . $args->link_before . '<span class="menu-item-description">' . $item->description . '</span>' . $item->title, $item_output );
  }
  return $item_output;
}
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'prefix_nav_description', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: I just ran the function above and ran into no issues. `Example ' description " here` is what the description I used was.

Comment: I am wondering if WP is converting the single quote to &#8217; When you run the code with that, instead of the apostrophe, does it work? (Thanks for your help)

Comment: I still have no issues with the above. Are you using the latest version of WordPress (4.8)?

Comment: Weird. I am on 4.7.5, upgrading now...

Comment: It doesn't change the effect in 4.8.  Do you have any suggestions for how to escape the apostrophe or encode/decode it to see if that helps?

Comment: Maybe `htmlentities()`?